# LastPass fingerprint accepts all fingers?

Tags: firefox, fingerprint, lastpass

I accidently scanned the wrong finger on LastPass, and it logged me on! Then I asked my mother to scan her finger, and her finger worked too! What's wrong here? I haven't bought LastPass. (I'm just trying the fingerprint scanner. It's a trial on 15 days or so..) Could this be because my trial has ran out? (If so I don't think LastPass is good when it comes to security!)

UPDATE: According to my Device Manager, I have one of the Validity Sensors fingerprint scanners. I use a Dell Vostro 3350 with an i3, so maybe you know exactly which one it has. I use it to log into Windows, and here it works perfectly!

Comment: Their tech support is very responsive. Email them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably get a different password manager. That company has already been hacked twice and now anyone is scanning their finger and accessing your passwords?

Comment: Yes, but if they get hacked, can the hackers get anything out of the passwords, as they don't have the master pass thus the encryption key?

Comment: Nope they can't. Lastpass is using a very strong encryption method (`PBKDF2-SHA-256`) and a brute-force attack is near impossible. If you are paranoiac about brute-force attacks, you can increase iterations to make brute-force attacks even more unlikely  http://helpdesk.lastpass.com/security-options/password-iterations-pbkdf2/ . I consider myself a paranoiac. That's why I use 10 000 iterations!